# How is the frequency of a photon related to the gravitational force it exerts?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity, gravity, photons

I know that even though a photon has no mass it still has energy. From what i understand the mass and velocity of a photon have no bearing on the amount of energy it emits, rather its energy is dependent solely on the frequency that the particular photon is resonating. How is this frequency and the energy being emitted by it related to the gravitational force exerted from the photon? Does a photon resonating at a high frequency and short wavelength emit more of a gravitational effect than a photon resonating at a lower frequency?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, a photon's energy $E = \hbar \omega$ and momentum $p = (\hbar/c) \omega$ contributions to the stress-energy tensor of general relativity are both directly proportional to its frequency $\omega$.

Comment: Does my question if light is deflected by gravitational force depending on its wavelenght  relate to your answer?

Comment: @PeterBernhard I don’t follow your comment - which question are you referring to?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, "my" meant mine... Would you say that it depends on the wavelength in what angle gravitation of earth bends a beam? Again, sorry, this is my last comment as I am afraid to be removed to chat.